# tape/jest not recognizing test case

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, create-react-app, redux-saga-test-plan

Created an app using create-react-app.
I set up a test file with the suggested convention. But when I run **npm test**
seems, my test case is not recognized.

```
 FAIL  src\_tests_\saga.test.js
  ? Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\TestRunner.js:1
89:18)
      at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:103:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.941s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage
 > Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 > Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 > Press q to quit watch mode.
 > Press Enter to trigger a test run.
TAP version 13
# testflow Saga test
ok 1 take testflow
ok 2 test state should be false
ok 3 Must call bye
```

Comment: you should paste some code from saga.test.js

Comment: I am getting the issue error, even after adding test cases


    describe('Addition', () => {
      it('knows that 2 and 2 make 4', () => {
        expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
      });
    });

Test suite failed to run

Your test suite must contain at least one test.

    at onResult (node_modules\jest-cli\build\TestRunner.js:192:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal\process\next_tick.js:109:7)

Comment: Found the solution as of now https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1054 and is working for me.

Comment: @AshwinHegde Thanks. That worked. Not sure how to accept your answer. I just upvoted it